# S.M.A.R.T on Samsung SSD 950 PRO M.2

Tags: ssd, samsung, smart

smartctl reports: device lacks SMART capability, but Samsung says it supports SMART. Does anybody know the reason for this?

> === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
> Vendor:               NVMe
> Product:              Samsung SSD 950
> Revision:             BXX7
> Compliance:           SPC-4
> User Capacity:        256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
> Logical block size:   512 bytes
> Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
> Logical Unit id:      0x0025385cf1508633
> Device type:          disk
> Local Time is:        Sat Mar 18 11:27:32 2017 AEDT
> device is NOT READY (e.g. spun down, busy)
> SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

Comment: Is SMART enabled in the BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, is the Smartmontools > v6.5?

The command seem to be

```
smartctl -A
```

Based on [Smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/NVMe_Support)

```
Smartmontools NVMe support

Smartmontools supports NVMe starting from version 6.5. Please note, that currently NVMe support is considered as experimental. Currently implemented features:

Basic information about controller name, firmware, capacity (smartctl -i)
Controller and namespace capabilities (smartctl -c)
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result and warnings (smartctl -H)
NVMe SMART attributes (smartctl -A)
NVMe error log (smartctl -l error[,NUM])
Ability to fetch any nvme log (smartctl -l nvmelog,N,SIZE)
The smartd daemon tracks health (-H), error count (-l error) and temperature (-W DIFF,INFO,CRIT)
Currently NVMe support is implemented on Linux, Windows and FreeBSD. Details about supported version/driver combinations are provided in the next section.
```

Comment: It is, smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214, so 6.5. So self test should work... But as it's still experimental... Going to search some other tool then...