# How do you update your SSD firmware when Samsung doesn't provide a Linux tool?

Tags: ssd, firmware

They have windows and mac one, but no Linux:
http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html

How to update the m2 SSD firmware?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update samsung ssd firmware from ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348219/how-to-update-samsung-ssd-firmware-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: There is a risk of losing your SSD and the data stored on it when updating to a new firmware!**

Here are the steps:

1. Identify your SSD model by running `sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvmxxx` on your SSD (replace "xxx" by your actual device name); [here is an example output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894150/s-m-a-r-t-on-samsung-ssd-950-pro-m-2).
2. Prepare a bootable Ubuntu/Kubuntu USB stick, either from [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) or from [Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
3. Start your computer from the said USB stick.
4. Open a browser and search "Samsung SSD firmware" from any search engine; the first result should be the [SSD tools and software download page from Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/).
5. Scroll down until "Firmware", expand the section, find the ISO image matching your SSD model and download it.
6. Open the ISO image with an archive tool like [File Roller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller) or [Ark](https://apps.kde.org/ark/) (whatever comes preinstalled with your USB stick) and look for the file name `initrd` and extract it (drag and drop it outside of the archive and into your file manager window).
7. Open again the file `initrd` with an archive tool (you need to double click twice) and look for the folder `root/fumagician`; again extract it (drag and drop it outside of the archive).
8. Open a console (`F4` in some file managers), go inside the folder `fumagician` you just extracted and run `sudo ./fumagician`.
9. [Proceed through the steps of the SSD Magician tool](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/FM/201710/20171030110819064/Samsung_SSD_Firmware_Update_Utility_User_Manual_English.pdf); in my case the reprogrammimg was instant and there was no success or failure confirmation at the end. If the SSD Magician finds no devices then maybe you forgot to use `sudo`.
10. Restart without mounting or otherwise touching the content of the SSD you just updated.
11. After restart `sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvmxxx` should display the updated firmware version. In my case the updated firmware version would not show until the restart.

**Remark 1:** It seems possible to update from an OS running on the target SSD and I saw YouTube videos showing the SSD Magician tool on Windows doing such hot updates, i.e. on a SSD being used. But I am not entirely sure whether this is safe. The issue is that the OS will write to the SSD after the update procedure but before the restart. There is a risk that the SSD does not handle correctly those writes, hence losing data.

**Remark 2:** If UNetbootin is used to create a bootable USB stick from the ISO then the USB stick needs to be formatted with MBR and FAT32; GPT and/or ext4 did not work for me. There is a bug in the ISO image provided by Samsung with AMD based systems. USB and more specifically USB keyboards and mice will not work; since most modern mainboards do not have PS/2 ports anymore navigating through the SSD Magician prompts is virtually impossible on AMD based systems ([source](https://blog.quindorian.org/2021/05/firmware-update-samsung-ssd-in-linux.html/)).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer from an Apple MacBook user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387414) suggests that using `dd` to copy the ISO9660 CD image to an USB stick (at block device level, not a partition level) may work. I find this strange since it would mean that tools like [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) or [USB creator](https://packages.ubuntu.com/usb-creator) do essentially nothing besides calling `dd` on a device.